# Setting up DNS for Remote Access

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, dhcp, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have Windows 2012 with the DNS/DHCP features installed.

Do I need to install Active Directory and then add all my machines to the domain of local.FQDN.com for example?

I can do this and still use the local profiles/user names correct?

And then the AD will allow my clients to access their local resources and shares via names correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an Active Directory setup if all you want is a local DNS server.

Active Directory mainly serves to offer single [sign-on](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on), and a hierarchical [directory service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_service) (catalog of users and devices) to your domain, amongst other things but a local DNS and DHCP server can be run regardless of the Active Directory configuration.

And to answer the second part of your question, yes if you set up Active Directory on your network you can still use the local user accounts on each computer but that somewhat defeats the purpose of setting up Active Directory in the first place.

Accessing shared resources via name on the network is a function of DNS. Once again, you don't need Active Directory if that's all you want to do.